# Get number of different values in a column in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, distinct

I've tried more or less all combinations of `count` and `distinct` (except the correct one :)  ) in order to get the example below.

Input: table t1

```
NAME       |  FOOD
Mary       |  Apple
Mary       |  Banana
Mary       |  Apple
Mary       |  Strawberry
John       |  Cherries
```

Expected output:

```
 NAME      |  FOOD
Mary       |  3
John       |  1
```

N.B. Mary has Apple in two rows but she has 3 as we have 3 different values in the column.
I only managed to get 4 in FOOD Column for her, but I need 3 :(

Comment: What is the query you have tried so far?  Can you post that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.name as NAME, a.count(name) as Food 
from 
(SELECT distinct NAME,Food from table)a
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with a query which gives you unique combinations of *NAME* and *FOOD*:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.NAME, t1.FOOD
FROM t1
```

Then you can use that as a subquery in another where you can `GROUP BY` and `Count`:

```sql
SELECT sub.NAME, Count(*) AS [FOOD]
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT t1.NAME, t1.FOOD
        FROM t1
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, sum(a.FoodCount) from(
select distinct name,COUNT(food) as FoodCount from #t1 group by name, food ) as a group by a.name order by 2 desc
```